# Number of observations when using plm with first differences

Tags: regression, stargazer, plm

I have a simple issue after running a regression with panel data using `plm` with a dataset that resembles the one below:

```
dataset <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 2),
                      time = rep(c(0,1), each = 5),
                      group = rep(c(0,1,0,0,1), 2),
                      Y = runif(10,0,1))
model <-plm(Y ~ time*group, method = 'fd', effect = 'twoways', data = dataset,
            index = c('id', 'time'))
summary(model)

stargazer(model)
```

As you can see, both the model `summary` and the table displayed by `stargazer` would say that my number of observations is 10. However, is it not more correct to say that `N = 5`, since I have taken away the time element after with the first differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the number of observations. However, your code does not what you want it to do (a first differenced model).

If you want a first differenced model, switch the argument `method` to `model` (and delete argument `effect` because it does not make sense for a first differenced model):

```
model <-plm(Y ~ time*group, model = 'fd', data = dataset,
            index = c('id', 'time'))
summary(model)

## Oneway (individual) effect First-Difference Model
## 
## Call:
## plm(formula = Y ~ time * group, data = dataset, model = "fd", 
##     index = c("id", "time"))
## 
## Balanced Panel: n = 5, T = 2, N = 10
## Observations used in estimation: 5
## 
## Residuals:
##       Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
## -0.3067240 -0.0012185  0.0012185  0.1367080  0.1700160 
## [...]
```

In the summary output, you can see the number of observations in your original data (N=10) and the number of observations used in the FD model (5).

Comment: Thank you! I have seen that according to my code, plm would then would run a regression using the within estimator. That should give me the same results, right?

Comment: In general: No. In yourcase: for only two time points, the within one-way individual estimator yields the same results as the first-difference estimator. However, in your example you request the two-way within estimator.